# Абсолютный путь к файлу изображения

Tags: php

Задефайнил абсолютный путь к картинкам вот так вот :
`define ("PATH",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images");`
Но попытка вывести картинку ничего не дала :

```
<img src='<?=PATH.'/some.jpg'?> ' />
```

Потому что img требует пути вида `"http://"`, а не `"z:home/..."`
Так как тогда прописать в define абсолютный путь? Или я чего-то недогоняю?

Comment: Может так?

    define ("PATH","http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/images");

Comment: Замечательно, какую функцию тогда выполняет DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: Содержит путь к корневой директории сервера. Да в общем-то [информация не секретная](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php) ))

Comment: @Deonis, чтооо? 

    define ("PATH","/images");

Comment: exec, это относительный путь

Comment: @Deus, точно, ладно.

Comment: @Deus это абсолютный пусть, сколько вам раз говорить?